# reverse from an argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

We start with another empty string `t`. Then, considering each character of `s` in turn, add that character to the front of `t`.

After considering all of the characters in `s`, `t` is a copy of `s`, but in reverse order.

```
import sys
n= sys.argv[1]
i =0
while i < len(n):
    print n[::-1]
    i += 1
```

I don't know what to do with `t`. The code above works - prints argument `ih` to `hi` but prints `hi` five times. I just want it to print `hi` once on one line.

Comment: You're not using `t` anywhere... Also you don't need `i`...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use indexes for your code. What do you think this is doing?`n[::-1]`

Just use:

```
print n[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is

```
import sys
n = sys.argv[1]
t = ''
for c in n:
    t = c + t
print t
```

Or, other than slicing (see previous answers, probably the best solutions)

```
t = ''.join(reversed(n))
```